# How to set UTF-8 encoding with XMLRPC client library

Tags: php, xml, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib, xmlrpcclient

I'm using XMLRPC client to call Adestra API services. Currently I'm having problems inserting Bosnian letters č, ć, ž, đ, š.

I configured my XMLRPC client to work with UTF-8, but still having problems. Here my code sample:

```
//******* LOGIN DATA*******/
$account = 'account';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$adestraCoreTable=1;


/**INITIALIZE API*****/
require_once('xmlrpc.inc');//First inlcude XMLRPC client library


//Calling Adestra API with our credentials
$xmlrpc= new xmlrpc_client("http://$account.$username:$password@new.adestra.com/api/xmlrpc");
$xmlrpc->setDebug(0);
$xmlrpc->request_charset_encoding="UTF-8";


$msg = new xmlrpcmsg(
                    "contact.search",
                    array(
                        //Set user id
                        new xmlrpcval($adestraCoreTable, "int"),
                        new xmlrpcval(
                            array(
                                "firstName"=> new xmlrpcval("Čokolada", "string"),
                            ),"struct"
                        )
                    )

                );
$response = $xmlrpc->send($msg);//Send request, and get the response
```

The rest of the code is parsing the $response which is not our main interest here.

As you can see, the `firstName` is set to `Čokolada`, but when I check it in Adestra, I get the value `Äokolada`. Obviously, there is problem in encoding.

Anyone can help?

Comment: What's the source code's encoding, and did you use `use utf8;`?

Comment: File is written using Notepad++ and I used UTF-8 without BOM encoding!

Comment: Did you use `use utf8;`? If not, you don't actually have a "Č" in the source code.

Comment: I used UTF-8 encoding!

Comment: So you've said, but that doesn't answer my question. Did you tell Perl you used UTF-8 by using `use utf8;`?

Answer (score 5):

In xmlrpc.inc replace this

```
$GLOBALS['xmlrpc_internalencoding']='ISO-8859-1';
```

with this

```
$GLOBALS['xmlrpc_internalencoding']='UTF-8';
```